# .htaccess not allowing access to files in a directory

Tags: .htaccess

**Whats supposed to happen:**

Any file requests in the root directory that are on the list are to be processed as is.

Any file requests in the /images/ directory are to be processed as is.

Anything else passed to the root directory (just the root directory) should be sent to viewpic.php?id= and then the request

**What IS happening:**

Everything above is working, except when i attempt to visit an image from the /images/ directory it doesnt display, and instead displays my site index.

**My .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|php|swf|xpi|ico|src)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) view.php?picid=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `.htaccess` file does the following right now, per line:

1. Activates the Rewrite Engine.
2. Checks if the file doesn't end one of those extensions, **OR**
3. Checks if the request URI is /images/, **OR**
4. Checks if the file doesn't exist

Then rewrites... Which is not what you really want. You might want to try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^images/
RewriteRule (.*) view.php?picid=$1 [L]
```